# SSIS , I have two columns data and need to supply in to 1 output column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have below requirement .

1. I have 8 input columns and 113 out columns, In that i need to supply the data in to 7 Columns, means two columns data need to insert one column.
2. 10 Columns need to supply a value 0 ( hard code) and other columns should be Null value.

what i have tried

I have tried with derived column and able to supply two columns in to one columns, But i further i am not able to do that, I am getting sort errors

Could any one help me please